# Как удалить на всех страницах сайта одни и те же типичные слова (телефоны, реквизиты), чтобы вручную не удалять?

Tags: wordpress, cms, wordpress-плагины, контент

Сайт на базе Wordpress Вордпресс
Как удалить на всех страницах сайта одни и те же типичные слова (телефоны, реквизиты) , чтобы вручную не удалять ?

Через какой сервис или каким образом это можно сделать, чтобы не вручную каждую страницу заходить, страниц то много, и везде фигурирует одна и та же информация, какая не актуальна.

Или еще лучше как заменить одни фразы массово на сайте на другие фразы? Как Вы решаете эту проблему ?

Comment: Если вся информация хранится в БД, то просто через команду `UPDATE` и `REPLACE` запрос заменить все, что нужно. Если информация "прибита" руками в коде, то достаточно сделать поиск и замену по проекту(PhpStorm комбинация ctrl+shift+r).

Comment: @NikPashchuk нельзя в ВП лазить в базу руками! Тем более нубам. Причины те же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562 А "в коде" нормальные разработчики на ВП ничего такого не делают.

Comment: Зависит от того, где и что нужно менять. И что как сделано на конкретном сайте.

Comment: @SeVlad каков вопрос, таков ответ

Comment: @NikPashchuk Вопрос по ВП. Не надо давать опасных рекомендаций.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такие проблемы не появляются. Если, что-то нужно вывести более одного раза, то пишется некоторая функция `printSomething()` в которой реализован весь вывод. А потом эта функция вызывается из нужных мест.

А если вывод меняется, то достаточно изменить его в одном месте и он поменяется везде